# Playwright tests failing in macOS but passing in Windows

Tags: playwright

I have executed different Playwright tests in 3 Apple computers and many tests are failing because of an unexpected "refresh" of the browser during the execution.

What is weird is that the same tests are passing in Windows or Linux.

Do you have any idea of what may be causing this?